# Short story, electrical ghost running along the underside of a telephone line

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story in an anthology while standing in a Barnes and Noble in the US, probably around 1996.  For some reason it stuck with me, and despite several years of intermittent searching, I can't seem to find it.

The story was about a man experiencing the afterlife - it turns out that when you die, you leave behind some kind of electrical or energy-based ghost.  The image that stuck with me is that electrical ghost running along the underside of power lines or telephone lines, I think at one point being chased by some sort of "crusher", perhaps a ghostly predator.

As well, I remember the narrator describing signals/screams coming from space, specifically from the Pleiades/Seven Sisters.  I think the implication was that the sky was full of electrical phenomenon only visible to ghosts like the narrator.

It was quite a vivid and unique story - I would love to read it again if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After Googling this one I found this discussion thread where someone else had asked about this in 2016 at [SFF Chronicles](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/563011/).

It was later discovered the story was "Radio Waves", by Michael Swanwick. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Swanwick) Swanwick won the 1996 WorldFantasy award for it.

It was published in a 1995 issue of [Omni magazine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29527755-omni-magazine-winter-1995) and more recently in an anthology called ["The Best of Michael Swanwick"](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/1596061781/1596061781__c_.htm)

It sounds like a really great story; I'm going to seek out a copy for myself.

The story opens with the protagonist running along the underside of telephone lines:

> I was walking the telephone wires upside-down, the sky underfoot cold and flat with a few hard bright stars sparsely scattered about it, when I thought how it would take only an instant's weakness to step off to the side and fall up forever into the night.

The "Seven Sisters" are a cluster of radio antenna:

> The antenna farm was visible from here. I could see the Seven Sisters
> spangled with red lights, dependent on the earth like stalactites. "Where are you running to, little one?" one tower whispered in a crackling, staticky voice.

The predator chasing him is called a "Corpsegrinder":

> [...] I slewed about to see what was coming after me.
>
> It was the Corpsegrinder.
>
> When it saw that I'd spotted it, it put out several more legs, extended a quilled head, and raised a howl that bounced off the Heaviside layer.

Comment: Amazing! This is absolutely it... thanks!  Can't wait to read the rest of his stories.